# Can 1 modal follow another with Bootstrap 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

Is it possible with bootstrap v2.3.1 to have one modal window open immediately after the preceding one closes? That is:

1. user clicks button and first modal opens.
2. User closes modal and second modal opens.

I have tried doing this using the **hidden** event of the first modal, such that the second modal is opened in the callback for that event. However, the dark, transparent background of the 1st one remains visible and the second modal opens, but cannot be interacted with as it is under the dark transparent background.

Refer to the following image:

[image]

Thanks

**edit by OP**

The code in the onHidden event looks like this:

```
changeTypeConfirmModal.on('hidden', function () {
    var modalFormOptions = {
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        show: true,
    };

    modalForm.modal(modalFormOptions);  
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ud48dk5v/

use : hidden event - This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for css transitions to complete)

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
    //shows the second modal window
    $('#myModal2').modal('show')
})
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I was loading it in the hidden event of the first modal. My code is almost the same as yours.

Comment: You proved it's possible, so I'll give the answer. Would have been nice to solve my bug.

Comment: Can you put page online? It is hard to find the bug without the entire source

Comment: I wish I could, but I can't. I realize how hard it is to troubleshoot without access to the app/code. So we've reached an impasse. I've got authorization to redesign so 1 modal is not used. Not ideal, but it's the only thing I could do in the time-strapped environment.

Comment: if there is a error in console? Try removing additional javascript and css. Only bootstrap files should remain. See if it will thereafter remain overlap. Then add one by one additional file to see who has the error

Comment: There's no error in the console. I'l try removing those things. It could be tricky as there's a metric truckload of js flying around.